# Python Projects In VSCode Exit With "code=1" When I Try to Run Them as Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, exit-code

Title.

The specific message is:

> ```
> [Running] python -u "d:\VSCode Projects\python.py"
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.286 seconds
> ```

Non-python(specifically c++) projects work fine. Running and debugging the python file itself work normally. To be honest, I have no idea what the difference between running the code and running the file is. Would like to know the difference and why running the code doesn't work, as well as how to fix it if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest PyCharm for developing Python. It's free and in my opinion better than VsCode for Python

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 I did install Pycharm as well, but I'm interested to hear why you think it's better than VSCode for python; what features distinguish it from VSCode or other editors and IDEs for python specifically?

Comment: I prefer the code completion pycharm has. And most of all I like that pycharm automatically creates virtual environments for each project

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 What's a virtual enviroment?

Comment: you can install pip packages there. So for instance if you need version 2 of some package for a project and version 1 for another project, instead of having to swap them around all the time you can install the specific version in the virtual environment of the project

Comment: oh, but isn't that what workspaces are in VSCode as well? @ShadowCrafter_01

Comment: I don't know never looked into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. **Run Code**

This option is provided by the extension [Code-Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), which is not an official extension provided by Python. Of course, this extension itself has many interesting functions.

2. **Run Python File**

This option is provided by Python extension. It is an officially supported option to run Python files. Usually, we will use this option.

If you want to use the first one, you can add the following code to your `settings.json`:

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

If you don't want to use the first one, just delete the code runner extension in the extension store.

[image]

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for answering, but what are the differences between running the file and the code, if any?

Comment: The main thing is that they start in different ways. As I said in my answer, Run code is provided by the code runner extension, and run file is provided by the python extension。